# How to run React custom hook conditionally or inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a custom hook to redirect users to edit page. On index page I can duplicate items and delete. I can redirect users after duplicate, but the problem is when I delete an item, this custom hook redirects users to edit page again. So I need to find a way to make it work conditionally.

Custom hook:

```
export default function useDuplicateItem(url: string) {
  const { sendRequest: duplicate } = useHttpRequest();

  const duplicateItem = useCallback(
    (data) => {
      duplicate([
        {
          url: `/api/server/${url}`,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          data,
        },
      ]);
    },
    [duplicate, url]
  );
  useRedirectEditPage(url); // This causes the problem
  return duplicateItem;
}
```

index page:

```
 const duplicateItem = useDuplicateItem('documents'); 
// custom hook rendered here, which is not correct. I want to run it when duplicate function runs.
    
      const duplicate = useCallback(() => {
        const data = {
          name: copiedName,
          sources: singleDocument?.sources,
          document: singleDocument?.document,
          tool: singleDocument?.tool,
          access: singleDocument?.access,
        };
        duplicateItem(data);
      }, [copiedName, duplicateItem, singleDocument]);
```

useRedirectEditPage:

```
export default function useRedirectEditPage(slug: string) {
  const { saveResponses, setSaveResponses, setHeaderStates } =
    useAdminContext();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const statusCodes: number[] = [];
    let id;

    saveResponses.forEach((value) => {
      statusCodes.push(value?.status);
      id = value?.id;
    });

    if (statusCodes.length && id) {
      if (statusCodes.includes(404)) {
        setHeaderStates((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          canBeSaved: false,
        }));
      } else {
        router.push(`/admin/${slug}/edit/${id}`);
        setSaveResponses(new Map());
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [saveResponses, router, setSaveResponses]);
}
```

`saveResponses` state is coming after I make any request to server, and I am able to get `id` to redirect users. I use `new Map()` to `set` data inside saveResponses.

Comment: `useRedirectEditPage(url);` seems pretty unconditional. Are you sure it's the right tool for the job? Does `useRedirectEditPage` need to be so coupled to `useDuplicateItem`? I'd suggest refactoring the code to have the logic of redirecting or not live in the component. Can you [edit] to include this `useRedirectEditPage` hook and clarify the overall use case?

Comment: The application needs to redirect users to edit page after adding a new item, and duplicating an item. This was my solution for duplicate, but now I have delete feature and facing unnecessary redirect issue. I will update the question now. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what part is the "delete feature"?

Comment: It is also on the index page, but not related to `duplicate` at all. The only thing `useDuplicateItem` is rendering. And this causes `redirect` after delete. 
I guess, I will create a new `useState` `isItemDuplicated`, and send it to`useRedirectEditPage` as an argument then put it on the top level of `if` as a new condition.

Comment: Well, you ***can't*** conditionally call React hooks, and I think you need to decouple some of this "add/modify an item" logic from any "do a navigation action" logic.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I agree that it needs some refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

From the react docs:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
> Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function,
> before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that
> Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
> That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
> between multiple useState and useEffect calls. (If you’re curious,
> we’ll explain this in depth below.)

React relies on the order in which Hooks are called to know which `setState` corresponds to which `state`, calling them inside a condition will mess up the previous mechanism.

I would recommend to read the following: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation

Comment: While not incorrect this doesn't really answer the question or address any issues. It's barely more than a link to the docs.